# Handling hyperlinks with custom WebView renderer in Xamarin.Forms PCL

Tags: ios, webview, xamarin.forms

I have come across a problem in which I cannot open Urls in a custom webview which uses a custom renderer to authenticate to a back-end server. I am trying to open any hyperlinks pressed within the webview on an external browser (i.e Safari). However when I press a hyperlink, the webview does nothing. It even fails to trigger the WebView.Navigating event. My code is below:

```
public class AuthWebViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<AuthenticatedWebView, WKWebView>, IUIWebViewDelegate
{
    WKUserContentController userController;

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<AuthenticatedWebView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if(Control == null)
        {
            userController = new WKUserContentController();
            var config = new WKWebViewConfiguration { UserContentController = userController };
            config.IgnoresViewportScaleLimits = true;
            var webView = new WKWebView(Frame, config);
            webView.NavigationDelegate = new WebViewDelegate(this);

            SetNativeControl(webView);
        }
        if(e.OldElement != null)
        {
            userController.RemoveAllUserScripts();                
        }
        if(e.NewElement != null)
        {
            var htmlData = Element.Source as HtmlWebViewSource;
            Control.LoadHtmlString(htmlData.Html, new NSUrl("https://websiteineedtoaccess.com"));
        }

    }
    public class WebViewDelegate : WKNavigationDelegate, INSUrlConnectionDataDelegate
    {
        private AuthWebViewRenderer _renderer;
        public WebViewDelegate(AuthWebViewRenderer renderer)
        {

        }
        public override void DidReceiveAuthenticationChallenge(WKWebView webView, NSUrlAuthenticationChallenge challenge, Action<NSUrlSessionAuthChallengeDisposition, NSUrlCredential> completionHandler)
        {

            var user = SettingsModel.UserName;
            var password = CryptoManager.DecryptAes(SettingsModel.Password);
            completionHandler(NSUrlSessionAuthChallengeDisposition.UseCredential, new NSUrlCredential(user, password, NSUrlCredentialPersistence.ForSession));
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that there is a built in method to the navigation delegate that I could use to achieve my goal. The solution is posted below:

```
public override void DecidePolicy(WKWebView webView, WKNavigationAction navigationAction, Action<WKNavigationActionPolicy> decisionHandler)
        {
            if (navigationAction.Request.Url.ToString().Contains("http"))
            {
                var url = navigationAction.Request.Url.ToString();
                if (url.Contains("http"))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var uri = new Uri(url);
                        Device.OpenUri(uri);
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                    }
                }
                decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicy.Cancel);
            }
            decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicy.Allow);
        }
```

Simply place the above method into your custom WKNavigationDelegate and everything works fine.